# How do I change the text in the toolbar in each activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toolbar, settext

There are questions answered on this, however, they don't seem to work with the new AndroidX

My Main Activity is saying "Home" in the toolbar, when I want it to say something else. I'm only using the default navigation drawer activity from Android Studio

Here's my Main Activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {






@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Let's say I want to set the text of the toolbar as something, how do I do it?

Here's the styles.xml too for reference

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your requirements, you could statically change it by using:

`getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Some Title Here");`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:text="<your text>">

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: but where do i enter the text I want it to be?

Comment: @JohnB check I've edited where you can edit your text

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways to do that, as i am using **Material Design Dependency** i change my **AppTheme** from *resources* to this

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar>

        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Specifically this is the tag i am talking about

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar>
```

**EDIT**: In case if you want *Material Design Dependency* , here it is:

```
// New Material Design
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

Then go to your particular activity's XML and add custom toolbar, like so:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

Notice, here i have used **Linear Layout** just not to mess with constraints..

Then into your activity, do this:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)// this is your toolbar ID
        setTitle("Hello World") // your toolbar title

    }
```

ThankYou!